# is there a faster way to loop with ColorCounter in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops, counter

i have a lColorCounter code that works but it is slow. Is there a faster way to loop with lColorCounter?

```
  Dim rng As Range
Dim lColorCounter As Long
Dim rngCell As Range
Set rng = Sheets("MASTER LINE LIST").Range("C2:Z2000")
lColorCounter = 0
    For Each rngCell In rng
    'Checking BLUE color
        If Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then
            lColorCounter = lColorCounter + 1
        End If
    Next
Sheets("Status").Range("C5") = lColorCounter
lColorCounter = 0
    For Each rngCell In rng
    'Checking Yellor color
        If Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
            lColorCounter = lColorCounter + 1
        End If
    Next
Sheets("Status").Range("B5") = lColorCounter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop once:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim bColorCounter As Long
Dim yColorCounter As Long
Dim rngCell As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("MASTER LINE LIST").Range("C2:Z2000")
bColorCounter = 0
yColorCounter = 0
    For Each rngCell In rng
    'Checking BLUE color
        If rngCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then
            bColorCounter = bColorCounter + 1
        ElseIf rngCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
            yColorCounter = yColorCounter + 1
        End If
    Next
Sheets("Status").Range("C5") = bColorCounter
Sheets("Status").Range("B5") = yColorCounter
```